# SQL Database for Magic Cardgame

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

For school I am creating a deckbuilder website based on Magic the gathering. It's the project that decides if I get my degree or not. Trough the website from Deckbrew I have been able to get data like the following:

```
 [
      {
        "name": "About Face",
        "id": "about-face",
        "url": "https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards/about-face",
        "store_url": "http://store.tcgplayer.com/magic/urzas-legacy/about-face",
        "types": [
          "instant"
        ],
        "colors": [
          "red"
        ],
        "cmc": 1,
        "cost": "{R}",
        "text": "Switch target creature's power and toughness until end of turn.",
        "formats": {
          "commander": "legal",
          "legacy": "legal",
          "vintage": "legal"
        },
        "editions": [
          {
            "set": "Urza's Legacy",
            "rarity": "common",
            "artist": "Melissa A. Benson",
            "multiverse_id": 12414,
            "flavor": "The overconfident are the most vulnerable.",
            "number": "73",
            "layout": "normal",
            "price": {
                "low": 0,
                "average": 0,
                "high": 0
            },
            "url": "https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards?multiverseid=12414",
            "image_url": "http://mtgimage.com/multiverseid/12414.jpg",
            "set_url": "https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/sets/ULG",
            "store_url": "http://store.tcgplayer.com/magic/urzas-legacy/about-face"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

It's obvious that it's in jSon format. I have found the way to turn this into objects and the structure of the project is 4-layer MVC with entity framework and C#, which is working (kinda)...The problem is the database. I have been working on it for 2 months now and I am not getting any further. The thing I get stuck on is the database. I have not seen much on how to create databases and that's where it goes wrong. I don't get how to build the database. The creation itself would work if I figured out how to include certain things...

1) Formats: if the card is legal in a format, Formats is filled with: "legacy": "legal", "commander":"legal", ... so only the legal formats are included.

2) Types and colors are just plain arrays of words, but since I'm very bad with databases I don't even know how to figure this one out.

3) Editions is something completely different. It's an array of the object Edition which I believe has to have a table of its own. The problem here is that I thought I needed to use a foreign key but since it's an array of Editions I don't really know how to start doing that either.

4) and then there's Price: It always has 3 values: low, average and high which can be 0 if there's no price known.

So here you have it. To me this database is very complex or maybe I am making it too complex. Is there anybody who can help me to get this database organized so I can get on with my project, because I'm so lost at the moment that I feel I am not going to get this ready by the end of next month and that would be awful.

Comment: Hate to say it, but your questions are REALLY basic - maybe you should not get a degree (unless the degree means "Incompetent beginner"). You lack anything about databases (which is the most important part outside of game programming - pretty much every work on any company program has something to do with a database). The database is trivial.

Comment: Good point. Started to ask myself that question too... Thanks anyway for reading trough this. I'll go read some more Database design articles or something.

Comment: Also, it is true what you say. I am not cut out to do backend .I'm 40 years old, was a house painter before this and now I'm trying to do the thing I wanted to do for over 15 years. I doubted myself many times during this course and wanted to give up a lot of times but didn't. I noticed that I'm very good at front-end, designing websites. I know that this must sound stupid to most people but that's why I'm going to finish this project any way I can. It's very hard for me, and I know it shouldn't. Anyways, At least now I know that I should look more up and do even more than I'm doing now.

Comment: It is not - and to tell he truth, I am the opposite. I can do websites, but I adhore it and the complexities of HTML "issues" between browsers - but give me a mid tier to backend project and I shine. Anyhoe, 90% of all business applications DO use database and it gets a LOT more complex than this.... my answer down has a lot of keywords that should direct you to further reading.

Answer (score 1):

1: No, you should include all.

2: Table with colors, standard m:n binding table in between mapping the card table with the color table. Not knowing how to make a m:n relationship thing makes me thing you skipped all classes... this is fundamental and basic.

3: Seems like "cardedition" is the main table actually, and everything before is a master type table. Not sure-  I don't really do magic at all, so I lack what is called domain knowledge. Are cards changed so multiple editions exist? Why is that an array in json?

3: magic values, 0,1,2,3. What is the question?

> To me this database is very complex

I suggest you start from scratch (making things easier) and just have maybe 10 or so tables. Go step by step. Follow what you learned, go to 3rd of 4th normal form and go relational.

Comment: 3) Edition is the set it came out in. A card can have multiple editions, something like a reprint.
4) is the Price. It has 3 values. For example: low: 3.40, average 4.00 and high 5.10 or something. Should Price have a table of its own?

Comment: Which is ONLY relevant if the cards CHANGE. But in this case, the "card" is just a placeholder entry, and cardedition is where the real data is stored. Happens.